What are common parametric forms for VIX smiles?
It is common in SPX markets to fit smiles using Stochastic volatility-inspired and Surface stochastic volatility-inspired parametric forms introduced by Gatheral and Jacquier (2014). In VIX markets what are the most common parametric forms for the smiles?

The implied vols for VIX options look really wierd https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EVIX/options/ it is more like a rictus than a smile.

I know. Just sticking to the usual name

I am saying: it is a good question you ask because I doubt that previous work on SPX smile with SV is applicable. It is a "different kettle of fish".
